# "except" function not working with discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I am new to developing discord bots and have encountered an issue. the "except" function is not working and draws a syntax error.

The error that it draws is here:

File "bot.py", line 36
except MissingRequiredArgument:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

And the code is here:

````
import random
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready!")
    await client.change_presence(activity = discord.Game("with fire"))

@client.command()
async def eightball(ctx, *, question):
    repsonses = [ 'It is certain.',
    'It is decidedly so.',
    'Without a doubt.',
    'Yes – definitely.',
    'You may rely on it.',
    'As I see it, yes.',
    'Most likely.',
    'Outlook good.',
    'Yes.',
    'Signs point to yes.',
    'Reply hazy, try again.',
    'Ask again later.',
    'Better not tell you now.',
    'Cannot predict now.',
    'Concentrate and ask again.',
    "Don't count on it.",
    'My reply is no.',
    'My sources say no.',
    'Outlook not so good.',
    'Very doubtful.']
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Fireplace", description=(f'{repsonses[random.randint(0, 20)]}'), colour = discord.Colour.orange())
    embed.set_footer(text = " By logiccc", icon_url="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C6F-YfVUwAE91mv.jpg")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
except:
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Fireplace", description=("Sorry! Something went wrong... The command syntax is .eightball <question>"), colour = discord.Colour.orange())
    embed.set_footer(text = " By logiccc", icon_url="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C6F-YfVUwAE91mv.jpg")
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Fireplace", description="Pong!", colour = discord.Colour.orange())
    embed.set_footer(text = " By logiccc", icon_url="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C6F-YfVUwAE91mv.jpg")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)```
I have no idea why this happens. Anyone else know?
Edit: I have tried the code in the comment but it doesn't work. I just keep getting the error message in the console and no reply from the bot. Any tips?
````

Answer (score 1):

You are using `try-except` the wrong way, take a look at the comments I left in the code below. You can learn about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp).

```py
@client.command()
async def eightball(ctx, *, question):
    repsonses = ['It is certain.',
                 'It is decidedly so.',
                 'Without a doubt.',
                 'Yes – definitely.',
                 'You may rely on it.',
                 'As I see it, yes.',
                 'Most likely.',
                 'Outlook good.',
                 'Yes.',
                 'Signs point to yes.',
                 'Reply hazy, try again.',
                 'Ask again later.',
                 'Better not tell you now.',
                 'Cannot predict now.',
                 'Concentrate and ask again.',
                 "Don't count on it.",
                 'My reply is no.',
                 'My sources say no.',
                 'Outlook not so good.',
                 'Very doubtful.']
    try:  # Try to do this 
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Fireplace", description=(f'{repsonses[random.randint(0, 20)]}'),
                              colour=discord.Colour.orange())
        embed.set_footer(text=" By logiccc", icon_url="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C6F-YfVUwAE91mv.jpg")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    except:  # If can't then do this
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Fireplace", description=(
            "Sorry! Something went wrong... The command syntax is .eightball <question>"),
                              colour=discord.Colour.orange())
        embed.set_footer(text=" By logiccc", icon_url="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C6F-YfVUwAE91mv.jpg")
```

Comment: I edited the post, please check it out because the error is too long to include it here :)